# Error running Junit test from IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, junit, junit4

I running a Junit test from IntelliJ IDEA, but I have this error:

```
Error running 'BookingTest': 
Command line is too long. Shorten command line for BookingTest or also for JUnit default configuration
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change [the corresponding option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eCLe.png) for the active and Template configurations you are using for the tests.